# how to sum up values of specific columns from multiple file

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have multiple data files. All of them contain 4 columns. I want to sum up each value on the third column with its respective value in all previous files (The same for fourth column). the first and second column needs to be untouched. finally, save the final value as a result in a separated output file.
I have written down the code up to a point but I don't know how should I move further to get what I want.

````
```
import glob
import numpy as np
# Reading the inputs
path = r'C:\Users\hp\Desktop\test\vdfi-0**-01000000'
my_files = glob.glob(path)
#print(len(my_files))
# opening an Output file
f=open(r'C:\Users\hp\Desktop\test\vdfi.txt',"a+")
#
x = 0 
for files in my_files:
    FR=open(files,'r')
    arr=np.loadtxt(FR.name)
    Vpara=arr[:,0]; Vperp=arr[:,1];F=arr[:,2]; dF=arr[:,3]
#    F[:,i]#+=F[i+1]
    print(F)
    for i in F:
        print(i+(i+1))
#    print(F[:])
```
````

This is just two samples of how my input files look.

```
vdfi-000-01000000
     -0.2900E+00      0.5000E-02      3.0000E+00      2.0000E+00
     -0.2900E+00      0.1000E-01      5.0000E+00      3.0000E+00
     -0.2900E+00      0.1500E-01      7.0000E+00      4.0000E+00
     -0.2900E+00      0.2000E-01      9.0000E+00      5.0000E+00
     -0.2900E+00      0.2500E-01      1.1000E+01      6.0000E+00
     -0.2900E+00      0.3000E-01      0.0000E+00      7.0000E+00
     -0.2900E+00      0.3500E-01      0.0000E+00      0.0000E+00
     -0.2900E+00      0.4000E-01      0.0000E+00      0.0000E+00
     -0.2900E+00      0.4500E-01      0.0000E+00      0.0000E+00
     -0.2900E+00      0.5000E-01      0.0000E+00      0.0000E+00
      ...             ...             ...             ...

vdfi-001-01000000
     -0.2900E+00      0.5000E-02      2.0000E+00      8.0000E+00
     -0.2900E+00      0.1000E-01      4.0000E+00      3.1000E+00
     -0.2900E+00      0.1500E-01      6.0000E+00      6.0000E+00
     -0.2900E+00      0.2000E-01      8.0000E+00      4.0000E+00
     -0.2900E+00      0.2500E-01      1.0000E+01      4.0000E+00
     -0.2900E+00      0.3000E-01      0.0000E+00      1.0000E+00
     -0.2900E+00      0.3500E-01      0.0000E+00      0.0000E+00
     -0.2900E+00      0.4000E-01      0.0000E+00      0.0000E+00
     -0.2900E+00      0.4500E-01      0.0000E+00      0.0000E+00
     -0.2900E+00      0.5000E-01      0.0000E+00      1.0000E+00
      ...             ...             ...             ...

The expected output for just these two files would be:
vdfi.txt
     -0.2900E+00      0.5000E-02      5.0000E+00      1.0000E+01
     -0.2900E+00      0.1000E-01      9.0000E+00      6.1000E+00
     -0.2900E+00      0.1500E-01      1.3000E+01      1.0000E+01
     -0.2900E+00      0.2000E-01      1.7000E+01      9.0000E+00
     -0.2900E+00      0.2500E-01      2.1000E+01      1.0000E+01
     -0.2900E+00      0.3000E-01      0.0000E+00      8.0000E+00
     -0.2900E+00      0.3500E-01      0.0000E+00      0.0000E+00
     -0.2900E+00      0.4000E-01      0.0000E+00      0.0000E+00
     -0.2900E+00      0.4500E-01      0.0000E+00      0.0000E+00
     -0.2900E+00      0.5000E-01      0.0000E+00      1.0000E+00
      ...             ...             ...             ...
```

Now extend these two to more than 100 files. As a result, I need to have only one file contain the sum of all the previous files for each value based on its respective one on the other files. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: OK let me make sure I understand your code properly, is F a column of numbers that you need to add to a grand total (presumably the variable x which you set to zero in the initialisation)?

Comment: @PaulaThomas Yes, F is the third column of number which I need the total amount of each value of it in my final output. I didn't know how to take the third column (F) of each files, added to the respective value in the next file and then move to the next up to the final file.

Comment: Sorry for the three day delay in getting back, travelling. Why can't you simply set a variable to 0, put thec filenames in a list, iterate over that list with a for loop, read each line of the file, extract the0 third number from the line and add it to the variable.

Comment: @PaulaThomas Thanks for your comment. I am newbie in python language. I have tried to do it but the loop iterate on the values over the initial file. it doesn't go from one to another. I don't know how to read a column from one file then add to the next, which should go on till the final file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to my good friend, I could find the answer. I am writing down the answer, so it can be helpful for others as well.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import numpy as np
path = "C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\test\\New folder\\"
#print(path)
final_df = None
for file in os.listdir(path):
#    print(file)
    df = pd.read_csv(path+file, header = None, sep = '     ',engine = 'python')  
    #Convert to numeric
    for col in df:
        df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col])
    if final_df is None:
        final_df = df.copy()
    else:
        final_df[2] = final_df[2]+df[2] 
        final_df[3] = final_df[3]+df[3] 
np.savetxt('C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\test\\vdf1.txt', final_df, fmt='%16.4e' , newline="\r\n")
```